# ExpressJs(NodeJs) Fire & Forget

Tags: javascript, node.js, fire-and-forget

I am currently developing APIs in express js. I want to write a function to which saves the analytic in DB but I should be able to call the function in fire and forget way. The function should accept parameters and do its work. This should work like a separate thread and current code execution should not wait for its response. For example the way Akka Actors work in Java. Can someone suggest a way to do it or some link to refer?

Answer (score 2):

Node is async by default. Just send your response outside of the db query callback:

```
app.get("/ping", function (req, res) {
    // fire
    dbConnection.query("UPDATE analytics SET count = count + 1", function(err, result) {
        // forget
    });

    res.send("Pong");
});
```

Comment: I believe he wants to have more space when dealing with errors; using MQ's allows him to retry db insert if it fails or even do some preprocessing

Comment: @VladMiller There is still space to handle errors in this simple approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your information to some kind of MessageQueue and then launch another process which will listen for MQ and process messages accordingly.

It's not particularly how Actors work, but that's how it's usually done in nodejs realm.

For example you can use [kue](https://github.com/Automattic/kue) or [AWS SQS](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) or [Google PubSub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs) or any other available solution

```
// example with kue
// http-process.js
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();

... 
app.post('/something-somewhere', (req, res) => {
  var job = queue.create('event', {
    data: 'analytics, data',
    median: 5.3,
  }).save( function(err){
    if( !err ) return next(err); 

    res.send('ok');
  });
});

// event-processor.js
var kue = require('kue');
var queue = kue.createQueue();

queue.process('event', function(job, done){
  someKindOfORM.myEventsTable.insert({
    job.data
  }).notify(done);
});
```

Comment: Oh that is a nice solution. But do you think Promises can help me in some way? I am not familiar with promises. Just asking.

Comment: I thought there also Promise concept in Akka as well, isn't it? Basically, promises are the way how to handle your sync code. I will add sample for you now

Comment: @SagarGopale here is good tutorial to understand promises http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/ . Promises are not meant to run in separate process, however they're meant to simplify process of async code. It's pretty hard to explain until you experience callback-hell first

Comment: Thank you for the reference link and the solutions above. I think these can help me out. :)

Comment: @SagarGopale here is good explanation for you what is the diff between callbacks and promises https://github.com/vasanthk/async-javascript#callback-hell